# Век и вечность.

Tags: словообразование, этимология

Есть слово «вечность» – то, что вне времени: без  начала, конца, без, каких бы то ни было,  ограничений. По сути, состояние вечности – это состояние Бога. И есть «век» - столетний отрезок времени, то есть, понятие, ограниченное этой сотней лет. Выходит, человек – столетняя частица бога, на материальном плане, естественно. В связи с этим, хочу задать следующих два вопроса: 1) Слово «век» породило «вечность», или «вечность» породила «век»? 2) Откуда эти слова происходят?

Answer (score 3):

ИЗ ТОЛКОВОГО СЛОВАРЯ

ВЕК,  1. Промежуток времени в сто лет.  2.Исторический период времени.Каменный век.  3. Жизнь, период существования.  Прожить свой век. 4. Разг. Очень долгое время. Не видеть кого-л. целый век.

ВЕЧНЫЙ,  1. Бесконечный во времени, не имеющий ни начала ни конца. Вечная материя.
2.Не перестающий существовать; сохраняющийся многие века. Вечная мерзлота.  3. Бессрочный. Передать на вечное хранение.  4 . Разг. Постоянный, неизменный. Вечные споры.

ВЕЧНОСТЬ, 1. Бесконечное по времени существование материального мира. Вечность материи.2. Книжн. Течение времени, не имеющее ни начала ни конца. Отойти (кануть) в вечность . 3. Разг .О времени, тянущемся очень долго. Не виделись целую вечность!

ЭТИМОЛОГИЯ

В др.-рус. языке известно с 11 века в форме векъ – жизнь, тысячелетие, время, вечность.  Общеславянское слово, имеющее индоевропейский корень с первоначальным значением "сила". Изменение значения идет по схеме: сила – жизненная сила – здоровье – долгая жизнь – продолжительность жизни человека – столетие – продолжительное время, эпоха.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Век – это сила, запас жизненных сил. Затем веком по смежности начинают измерять время, на которое хватит этого запаса.  Век становится временем  существования данного явления. По отношению к человеку – около 100 лет. Теперь век -  ЕДИНИЦА ИЗМЕРЕНИЯ времени. Очень длительный промежуток  измеряется веками, их количество может уходить в бесконечность.

Вечный (изначально)– это признак, отнесенный к веку, то есть ко времени существования  данного предмета/явления. Если существование предмета длится много веков, если оно мыслится как не имеющее предела, то такое существование называется  вечностью.

Comment: То есть, всё-таки "век" порождает "вечность". По законам словообразования получается именно так, но по сути... Если же век - это жизненная сила, предназначенная для чело-века и сгенерированная в среднем на сто лет, то, в принципе, всё можно расставить на свои места: человеку доступно понимание того что конечно и он переводит это во временные рамки, называя "веком" и, осознавая то, что существует нечто за гранью этих ограничений, за гранью осознания, он порождает такое понятие как "вечность". Можно было бы принять ваш ответ, он мне нравится, но на уровне интуиции, что-то мешает мне сделать это

Answer (score 2):

Я сейчас выскажу только свою точку зрения.
Мне кажется, что понятие "век" имеет значение не только "сто лет", но и просто "очень большой отрезок времени", как мы говорим иногда "их там миллионы", подразумевая исключительно большое количество, но не конкретное количество.
Отсюда и "вечность" - бесконечно большой отрезок времени.
Думаю, как-то так.

Answer (score 2):

да уж, хилая этимология.
Скорее «век»---сокращение, от веко.

веко ве́ко диал. "крышка туеса или лукошка", арханг. (Подв.), укр. вiко, блр. ве́ко, др.-русск. вѣдѣ дв. ч., словен. véka ж. "крышка, веко", véko "веко", чеш. víko "крышка", слвц. veko, польск. wieko, в.-луж. wjeko, н.-луж. wjeko. Родственно лит. vókas "веко", vóka "крышка", лтш. vâks "крышка"; возм., также алб. vétullë ж. "бровь" (из *vōklā); см. Траутман, BSW 347 и сл.; М. – Э. 4, 378; Лескин, Abl. 378; Bildung 179; Эндзелин, KZ 62, 25; Г.Майер, Alb. Wb. 469. Чтобы понять характер чередования гласных, ср. ре́па, мел; см. Фортунатов у Когена, ИОРЯС 23, 1, 22. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973.

2-е значение: Кожаная складка глаза, тоже со значением крышки.

в словацком - viečko, в словенском - vek, украинский - повіку

Видимо когда веки у мертвого закрывают, получается конец жизни.

А еще  в гроб кладут, сверху крышка - веко.  Нынче так и говорят—конец, крышка.
То есть век   идет от обряда.

Увечить - попортить нормальную жизнь, век укоротить, калеки долго раньше не жили.

ЧЕЛОВЕК- челом старый, поживший немало. Муж. Мужик.

Фасмер связать двух русских слов не смог, у него это в словаре частенько, немчура одним словом,  а потому вывел «век» и «человек» от литовско-латинской силы и ее применения.

«век род. п. века, ве́чный, сюда же уве́чный, укр. вiк, ст.-слав. вѣкъ αἰών, вѣчьнъ, болг. век, мн. ч. векове́, сербохорв. Ви̏ jек, ве̑к, словен. vȇk, чеш. věk, слвц. vek, польск. wiek. Родственно лит. viẽkas "сила, жизнь", veikiù, veĩkti "действовать, делать", véikus "проворный, быстрый", veiklus "деятельный, активный, деловой", vỹkis м. "жизнь, живость", vikrùs "бодрый", лтш. vèicu, vèikt "добиваться, пересиливать, одолевать", др.-исл. veig ж. "сила", víg ср. р. "борьба", гот. weihan "бороться", д.-в.-н. wîgan "бороться", ирл. fichim "борюсь" (из *vikō), лат. vincō, vincere "побеждать", pervicāx "упорный, стойкий"; см. Траутман, BSW 339; М. – Э. 4, 524 и сл.; Вальде 838; Торп 408. •• [См. еще Унбегаун, Sybaris, 173 и сл. – Т.] Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973»

«человек челове́к род. п. -а; диал. челэ̀к, дмитровск., чилэ̀к, обоянск.; укр. чоловíк "муж, супруг", блр. челове́к, др.-русск. человѣкъ, ст.-слав. чловѣкъ ἄνθρωπος, болг. члове́к, чове́к, челя́к, чиля́к, сербохорв. чо̀вjек, чо̏вjек, словен. člóvẹk, род. п. človẹ́ka, чеш. člověk, слвц. človek, польск. czɫowiek, в.-луж. čɫowjek, н.-луж. сɫоwjеk, полаб. clúovak. Праслав. *čelověkъ или сокращенное из него –* čьlověkъ, откуда лтш. cìlvę̃ks "человек"; см. М.–Э. I, 382 и сл.; И. Шмидт, Vok. 2, 39. Прочие реконструкции невероятны; см. Бернекер I, 140 и сл.; Шахматов, Очерк 152. Первая часть – čеlо- – сближается с че́лядь, далее – с др.-инд. kúlam "стадо, множество, семья, род", греч. τέλος "толпа", ирл. cland, сlаn "потомство, род", лит. kìltis, kiltìs "род". Во второй части усматривают слово, родственное лит. vaĩkas "мальчик, ребенок", лтш. vaiks – то же, др.-прусск. waiх "слуга" (Циммер, AfslPh 2, 347; Фортунатов, ВВ 3, 57; М.–Э. 4, 436; Бернекер I, 141; Младенов 687; Мейе, RS 2, 63; Траутман, ВSW 339; Арr. Sprd. 455; Ягич, AfslPh 13, 294; 30, 295). Другие ученые пытаются, что менее правдоподобно, установить в *čьlо ступень чередования к cělъ (см. це́лый), которая больше нигде не засвидетельствована, а в -věkъ – знач. "сила" (в противоположность слову уве́чье, см.), то есть первонач. "исполненный силы"; см. Потебня и Брандт, Сб. Вс. Миллеру 308 и сл.; Вайан, ВSL 39, 2, XIII и сл. (здесь – "совершеннолетний"). Этой этимологии противоречит др.-русск. форма человѣкъ. Еще менее удовлетворительны др. гипотезы, напр. сближение первой части* čеlо- с д.-в.-н. helid "герой" и греч. κέλωρ "сын" (Бругман, IF 12, 26; 19, 213; против см. Бернекер, там же; Буазак, МSL 17, 113) или с греч. πάλλΒ̄ξ, πάλληξ "юноша, девушка", παλλάκιον ̇ μειράκιον (Гесихий), παλλακή, παλλακίς "наложница" (Фик, ВВ 18, 134; Бецценбергер, ВВ 16, 249), потому что эти греч. слова не считаются теперь исконными; см. Гофман, Gr. Wb. 251; Шахматов, ИОРЯС 17, 2, 322. Мало что дает польск. сhоrоwiеk "болезненный человек", которое производит впечатление эфемерного шутливого образования; см. Бернекер (там же) против Карловича (Sɫown. gwar polsk. I, 199), Пастрнека (LF 29, 304). В пользу -věkъ в знач. "сила", кроме примеров, приводимых на век (см. выше), может также свидетельствовать диал. обезве́кнуть "ослабеть", арханг. (Подв.). •• [См. еще Мошинский, JР, 33, 1953, стр. 352 и сл.; Трубачев, Терм. родства, стр. 173 и сл., где имеется также сводка прочих маловероятных этимологий. Неудачные новые предположения приводятся Пизани ("Раidеiа", 12, No 5, 1957, стр. 309), Отрембским (LР, 7, 1959, стр. 296 и сл.); оригинальную, местоименную этимологию см. Мартынов, "Русск. и слав. языкознание. К 70-летию Р. И. Аванесова", М., 1972, стр. 185 и сл. – Т.] Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973»

Литовский veik prv. 1. скоро, вскоре; 2. почти    и где тут век и вечность, рядом не стоят.
А это корень  в словах, перечисляемых Фасмером, относится к быстроте действия--работе, скорости движения, но никак не к силе, а тем более к существованию - жизни. Жизнь, она конечно коротка – век, но это совсем другое слово в литовском, да и то вышедшее из употребления, старое viẽkas,  тянутое из русского.

Answer (score 1):

У Ожегова среди значений слова "век" есть такое:

> > 4) век, веком. Очень долгое время, вечность. Не век же тебя дожидаться. Целый век ждать писем. Век дома сидит. Этот день показался ему веком.